Entity Framework Core logging - can't see how the generated query is bringing back my data
My simple test app, which I set up to diagnose another issue I was having, seems to be retrieving associated data from a table that I wasn't expecting, and when I turn on logging I can see no reference to that table in the generated SQL.
My test app has two simple entities, a Band, each of which can have many Albums. After setting up some test data, I run a query to return one of the Bands, and it seems to come back along with its associated Albums, even though I didn't ask for them, and I don't see any reference to the Album table in the generated SQL logged by Entity Framework.
The entities look like this.
public class Band
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string BandName { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; } = [];
}

public class Album
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public Guid BandId { get; set; }
    public Band Band { get; set; }
}

I'm setting up logging as follows, in the OnConfiguring method: -
optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

After setting up a bunch of test data (which I won't paste here for brevity) I run the following simple test code: -
Band band = context.Bands.Where(b => b.BandName == "The Cure").Single();
List<Album> albums = band.Albums;
Console.WriteLine($"{band.BandName} has released {albums.Count} albums: -");
foreach (Album album in band.Albums)
{
    Console.WriteLine(album.AlbumName);
}

I actually expected that my Albums collection would be empty, since I hadn't added an Include to my initial LINQ statement. But the albums collection is fully populated, so the code lists out the Albums for that band. Fair enough, but looking at the generated SQL statement from the logging, I don't see anything that's referencing the Albums table in any way. Here's the sum total of the SQL that appears in the logging: -
SELECT "b"."Id", "b"."BandName"
FROM "Bands" AS "b"
WHERE "b"."BandName" = 'The Cure'
LIMIT 2

Incidentally, if I do add the include statement then the generated SQL does reference the Albums table as I'd expect, and the rest of the code executes in exactly the same way, producing the same output.
Can anyone offer any assistance in solving this mystery?
Edit: Adding full code of my sample app below, as requested by a commenter.
This is the code of the DB Context class: -
    public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly SqliteConnection DbConnection;

        public MusicContext(SqliteConnection dbConnection)
        {
            DbConnection = dbConnection;
        }

        public DbSet<Band> Bands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            AddRelationships(modelBuilder);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(DbConnection);
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }

        private void AddRelationships(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
                        .HasOne(a => a.Band)
                        .WithMany(b => b.Albums)
                        .HasForeignKey(a => a.BandId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        }
    }

And here is the complete code of Program.cs, which sets up the test data, then retrieves one of the bands, then outputs is details as a test: -
SqliteConnection connection;
connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
connection.Open();
MusicContext context = SetupDbWithEntities(connection);
OutputTestData(context);

void OutputTestData(MusicContext context)
{
    Band band = context.Bands.Where(b => b.BandName == "The Cure").Single();
    List<Album> albums = band.Albums;
    Console.WriteLine($"{band.BandName} has released {albums.Count} albums: -");
    foreach (Album album in band.Albums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(album.AlbumName);
    }
}

MusicContext SetupDbWithEntities(SqliteConnection connection)
{
    MusicContext context = new MusicContext(connection);

    if (context.Database.EnsureCreated())
    {
        Band band1 = new()
        {
            BandName = "The Cure"
        };
        context.Bands.Add(band1);

        Band band2 = new()
        {
            BandName = "Pink Floyd"
        };
        context.Bands.Add(band2);

        Album album1 = new()
        {
            AlbumName = "Seventeen Seconds"
        };
        band1.Albums.Add(album1);

        Album album2 = new()
        {
            AlbumName = "Disintegration"
        };
        band1.Albums.Add(album2);

        Album album3 = new()
        {
            AlbumName = "Wish"
        };
        band1.Albums.Add(album3);

        Album album4 = new()
        {
            AlbumName = "The Dark Side of the Moon"
        };
        band2.Albums.Add(album4);

        Album album5 = new()
        {
            AlbumName = "Wish You Were Here"
        };
        band2.Albums.Add(album5);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();

    return context;
}


We need the full picture. Please provide your configuration code, or the whole code of your test app.

You aren't searching Albums, you're searching bands using Single, a method used to ensure there's only one result, not 2 or more. That's exactly what the query should look like. If the Album objects are already loaded, there's no reason to go back to the database

Keep in mind that EF isn't a data driver. It's an ORM. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. Its job is to load, track and cache all the objects needed in a specific business scenario, along with their relations and commit all the changes to all the objects at once when the UoW commits - or discard all of them. If you load all albums, they remain cached and tracked as long as the DbContext exists. If you load a Band whose Albums are already loaded, DbContext will fix up the relations

BTW that's why you should never keep DbContext instances for long, or wrap them in pseudo-"repository" single-entity CRUD classes. EF is a far higher level abstraction than CRUDs

Thank you for the help! So my data is still hanging around in the DB Context from where I'm setting it up in the first place. That makes sense. And sure enough, if I get rid of the Context after setting up the test data, and create a new one before running the test code, then I get the results I expect.I had no idea EF would reattach the linked objects in that way. But if that's the case, why does it go to the database at all? All the band objects are also still in the Context, if it's getting the Album objects from there why not the bands too?

I will edit the question to post the full code above as requested. Apologies for not doing so in the first place, I only avoided it since the last question I asked here never got answered, and I assumed that might be because it looked so daunting with a huge amount of code posted, even though it was actually just a minimal test case. :)

The object (the DBContext) would need to be in scope for EF to use the entities that are already loaded (i.e. "in memory"). As noted above, you shouldn't be keeping DBContext around for long - they should be used to perform a unit of work and then disposed.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/#how-to-track-entities

I've edited full code into the question now. Thanks for the help everyone. I at least understand now where the Album data was coming from. I'm still somewhat mystified why that query goes to the database at all though, rather than also getting the Band objects from the existing DB Context too. You can see from the code above that they're still in scope.

I've read all the documentation in detail, including the link posted above, but I think I'm still misunderstanding something fundamental about EF, as its behaviour will often surprise and confuse me just when I think I'm beginning to understand it!

It went to the db because of Single. If you'd used Find to retrieve your band by PK, it wouldn't have gone to the DB - it would have just found the band in its local cache. EFC is this way by design - Find looks locally then remotely. First/Single/Last/enumerating/etc always hit the DB regardless of what is local. Don't return your context and keep onto it forever. Make a new one every time you have some small unit of work to do, or in more involved projects use dependency injection so that the injector injects a new context (or context factory) to any object that requires it

Also, you don't need to open the connection for EFC; it knows how to do that itself and you should let it manage connections unless you specifically need to do some fine grained transaction management

Amused me that you asked for a "Single", and it gave you an "Album"

Thanks @flackoverstow, I'd missed the fact there was such a distinction between Find and Single. Makes sense. Though I'm still mystified as to why, if Single is intended to always hit the DB, it does so for the Band but then happily goes to the cache to start fixing up links to Albums. I'd have thought it'd go to the DB for both, or (as I initially expected) not return them at all as I hadn't asked for them!

Having thought I'd read and absorbed the whole of the official EF docs, it still manages to surprise me from time to time by behaving in ways I just don't expect. Time to go back to the docs yet again I suppose, or perhaps I just need to find a better source to learn from?

And you're right, now you mention it, it is pretty funny that I call .Single but end up with a list of Albums!

If you want Single to hit the db for related Albums you should Include them. If you want a result with different relational wireup look at AsNoTracking and AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution

I didn't want to get the Albums at all! I was simply creating a minimal test case for a different issue entirely, and then got really confused why the Albums were coming back when I hadn't added an "Include" for them.

When it was explained in a comment above that EF fixes up the relationships to Albums because they're already in the Context, I'm fine with that, and I can just not re-use the Context and the confusion is solved.

But now I remain somewhat confused why it pulls Albums from the Context, yet it always goes to the DB to fetch the Bands, regardless whether they're in the Context or not. That seems kind of like inconsistent behaviour to me, but I'm enough of a noob to EF that I'll concede it's more likely a misunderstanding on my part of how things are meant to work!

It's okay to be confused. I have been confused by EF my entire life. You don't need to make excuses for yourself. However, I think it is an anti-pattern to put your DB context in a global scope. Each time you use the Context, you should create a context for that particular use, not "re-use it" over and over again. I can't tell because your "test code" has only one test, but it seems you would likely have many tests and use this same context repeatedly - that's not how EF is meant to work.

Thanks @topsail. You're totally right, using the same Context for my setup and my test was a dumb mistake, made due to cobbling together that minimal test case in a hurry. It's a mistake I'm kinda glad I made though, as it brought some more EF behaviour to my attention that I'd never have guessed at otherwise! I'm certainly using a different Context for every unit test in my production code though.

And thanks for the kind words about EF in general. I do love Entity Framework in principle, I just feel I have to be super-careful every time I do anything with it beyond very basic CRUD operations, else it might bite me in the ass by doing something fun and unexpected!

No worries ... I've actually copied some of the comments from this question myself as they are spot on and put into words some things I've been noticing myself over the years. I've been trying a few tests of my own based on your observations and these comments so we are all learning. For my own part, I am a Dapper guy if I have a choice but often I don't have a choice.
